# flask_sqlalchemy UPDATE row details not updating mySQL database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, crud

I have a flask app and a mySQL database connected to it. I am using POSTMAN to send GET/POST requests to the flask endpoints for user add, update and delete. I am able to successfully add users to the database but while I am updating the flask app does not throw any errors where as the postman also displays a successful JSON response that `"User updated!!!"` But when I perform `SELECT * FROM Users` operation in my SQL Workbench the details are not being updated.

My implementation is as follows -
I have created a model `User` with two columns `username` and `password`.

The user update API looks like -

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from model import User


class Update_User(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        usr = User.query.filter_by(username=data['username']).first()
        print(1, usr.username, usr.password)
        
        usr.password = data['new_password']
        print(2, usr.username, usr.password)

        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()

        return {"res": "User updated!!!!"}
```

flask output:

```
1 Ash 12345
2 Ash 00000
```

Just for better understanding, what is better to use ? Python SQLAlchemy or flask's own SQLAlchemy ? Because there are other instances as well where I am facing trouble like while updating two rows simultaneously using `add_all()`

Comment: Here is another variant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699360/flask-sqlalchemy-update-a-rows-information/70816760#70816760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling I found out where I was wrong, someone else facing the issue can try the following thing.

What worked for me -

```
usr.password = data['new_password']
db.session.merge(usr)
db.session.commit()
```

Things that did not work for me despite having them as answer on some of the stackoverflow questions -

```
usr.data["password"] = data['new_password']
db.session.commit()
--------------------------------------------
usr.password = data['new_password']
db.session.add(usr)
db.session.commit()
--------------------------------------------
usr.data = { "password": data['new_password'] }
db.session.commit()
```

Hope this might help you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the object to the session to tell SQLAlchemy that you want to you've made changes (after updating it, before committing):

```
usr.password = data['new_password']
db.session.add(usr)
db.session.commit()
```

See more details in the SQLAlchemy docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects

Comment: This does not work for me! However, if you might want to take an another look at your answer and replace `.add(usr)` with `.merge(usr)` it works  absolutely fine.

Comment: The error thrown while using your answer is `Object '<usr at 0xe4828>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')`

Comment: That sounds like you have loaded this user object into another session somewhere else: "Session.merge() transfers state from an outside object into a new or already existing instance within a session." -- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html Read the SQLAlchemy docs on sessions; you should only be working with one session at a time.