# flask SQL-Alchmey not returning a dictionary while querying

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

i am doubtful about my code. After looking for hours, was still not able to figure it out.

it's a very simple thing **where i am trying to query a table with a given id. Then i want to update the 'name' attribute with the passed name.**

But it's giving me an error- `TypeError: 'Bucket' object does not support item assignment`. `it's like its not returning a dictionary`

```
    # PUT REQUEST
    def put(self, id):
        bucket_to_update = bucket_db.query.get(id)   #### returns <Bucket id> , not dict
        print(bucket_to_update)  # prints the bucket as string

        if not bucket_to_update:
            return {"status": "failure"}, 404

        args = BucketAPI.parser.parse_args()
        name = args.get('name', None)

        bucket_to_update['name'] = name  # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PRODUCES AN ERROR
        db.session.commit()

        return {"status" "success"}, 200
```

#### Model - Bucket / bucket_db

```
"""Bucket model"""
from todo_app import db


class Bucket(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'buckets'

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )

    name = db.Column(
        db.Text,
        index=True,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    )

    items = db.relationship('Item',
                            backref=db.backref('bucket', lazy='joined'),
                            lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<bucket-{}> '.format(self.name)
```

From the [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701188/12210002), it is clearly visible that we can update the `details as dictionary`, but here its not working.

#### Erorr logs

```
    bucket_to_update['name'] = name
   TypeError: 'Bucket' object does not support item assignment
```

p.s- i am creating a Resource class to have different creation/deletion methods using flask-restful

## UPDATE (solved)

As pointed on comments and answers, its an object than a dictionary, you should access it as `bucket.name=name`. Plus I had missed a colon while returning.

Comment: Neither of those links show that you can use the object as a dictionary, but just as an object. `bucket_to_update.name = name` would match the syntax in your linked answer, _not_ `bucket_to_update['name'] = name`. There is also (usually) no need to explicitly commit with Flask-SqlAlchemy, since it'll do that as long as the returned status is not a 4xx or 5xx error.

Comment: @MatsLindh, i was blinded by that dictionary thing and half of time i was worried! Thanks  alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding** (3) at the end of `def put(self, id):`,
Correct `return {"status" "success"}, 200` to `return {"status":"success"}, 200`

(1) In your `class Bucket(db.Model):` you define the initialization function `__init__` so you override that of the parent class `db.Model`, so the `__init__` function of the parent class will not be invoked.

Therefore, try:

```
    def __init__(self, name):
        db.Model.__init__(self) ## *** invoke __init__ of the parent class
        self.name = name
```

(2) to update the modification in `bucket_to_update` in:

```
        bucket_to_update['name'] = name  # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PRODUCES AN ERROR
        db.session.commit()
```

add `db.session.add(bucket_to_update)` before commit:

```
        bucket_to_update['name'] = name  # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PRODUCES AN ERROR
        db.session.add(bucket_to_update)
        db.session.commit()
```

looking for your comments.

Good Luck.

Comment: @Hussein, i tried your things... its not working

Comment: I have added point No. (3) in the answer to modify, waiting for your comments

Comment: @Hussein, Thanks a lot.. Finally resolved it !!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to my coding environment but I reckon if you do following it should work fine.

```
    bucket_to_update.name = name
```