# Making updates to postgresql record using sqlalchemy in a flask application

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am able to insert records into the database:

```
new_user = Users(new_register_email, new_password, verification_code)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

[image: database query 1]

I am able to query records inserted out of the database:

```
 user_to_verify = Users.query.filter_by(email=uid).first()
```

[image: debug image 1]

I am not able to update records:

```
 user_to_verify = Users.query.filter_by(email=uid).first()
 if user_to_verify:
    if user_to_verify.verification_code == returned_verification_code:
        user_to_verify.verified = True
        db.session.commit()
```

[image]

With debugging I am verifying that the code listed above is run but the verified field in the database is not updated. This is fallowing info here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_updating_objects.htm

UPDATE:
image of debugger at point where update should occure
[image]

Comment: Is this: `user_to_verify.verification_code == returned_verification_code` returning `True`?

Comment: Yes am stepping though that in the debugger and the code is being hit

Comment: What is being shown in the Postgres server log?

Comment: let me figure out how to find the Postgres logs and I will add them. Thank you for your help

Comment: the logs folder is empty .... may take me a bit to figure out how to turn the logging up / on

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how valid this is but it seems to be working,
Added:

```
db.session.merge(user_to_verify)
```

before commiting
I found this solution here:
[Flask-SQLalchemy update a row's information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699360/flask-sqlalchemy-update-a-rows-information)

If this is not valid or bad practice please correct me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
user_to_verify.verified = True
db.session.add(user_to_verify)
db.session.commit()
```

you can also add

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

for debugging